# Dropzone.js not working, no errors

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js for uploading files, but it behaves strangely. When I open the page, the dropzone form doesn't show up, only the fallback field. When I drag & drop a file into the browser, the browser opens that file, then I use the Back button on the browser and Dropzone form shows up. I tried adding an alert inside the init function and it fires only when I press Back (the second scenario). There are no errors in the console. Here's the code:

```
<!-- Dropzone -->
<div id="dropzone">
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('/settings/upload'); ?>" class="dropzone" id="upload">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Dropzone -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/common/theme/scripts/plugins/forms/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.upload = {
        paramName: "info",
        maxFilesize: 0.1,
        init: function() {
            alert("test");
            this.on("error", function(file, msg) {
                alert(msg);
            });
            this.on("success", function(file, msg) {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON( msg );

                if (data.success) {
                    alert("success");
                } else {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was issue with cloudflare rocket loader. Exluded the two `<script>` statements from it using data-cfasync="false" and it worked.